# custom std::set.find() for a set of pointers

Tags: c++, set

```
class Node{
public:
    Node* back1 = nullptr;
    Node* back2 = nullptr;
    int value;

    Node(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    //bool operator< (const Node& rhs) const {return this->value < rhs.value;}
    bool operator< (const Node* rhs) const {return this->value < rhs->value;}
};

std::unordered_map<int, std::set<Node*>> nodes;

void subtractOneOrDouble(int current, int m, Node& prevNode) {
    if (current != 0 && current < m && nodes[current % 10].find(current) == nodes[current % 10].end()) {
```

I have a set of Nodes* and not only do I want to sort them by the value of each node, I want to use find(), input a value, and get the pointer to the node that corresponds to that value. From what I think is going on, find() is taking in pointers, not actual values. What would I need to change so that find() takes in an integer value and gives me the pointer to the Node with that value?

Comment: You need to supply comparator to set<Node*, comparator>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` takes as input the key type.  In your `std::unordered_map`, that key type is `int`, and in your `std::set` that key type is `Node*`.

If you want to use your elements' sorting, then you can change your `std::set`'s key to be `Node` instead of `Node*`.  [`std::set`'s comparison uses `operator <` (via `std::less`) by default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), so you can get this working with some tweaks to your code.  Here's an example that shows how finding by value can work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node(int v):value(v) {}
    bool operator <(const Node& rhs) const {
        return value < rhs.value;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<Node> nodes;
    nodes.emplace(1);
    nodes.emplace(2);
    nodes.emplace(3);

    auto found = nodes.find(Node(2));
    if (found != nodes.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found node " << found->value << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Didn't find node!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
Found node 2
```

As it is in your question, your `std::set` will be sorted by memory address (because that's how `Node*` is sorted), and not by `Node::value`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the expression

```
nodes[current % 10].find(current)
```

The index operator `[]` of the `std::unordered_map` will return a `std::set` (the value of the hash map). Then you apply the `find` function of the `std::set`. This set contains "Node*"s. But you are trying to find an `int` (current). This cannot work.

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but your are searching with the wrong type. You need to give a `const Node*` as aparameter to the find function.